# Observer returns empty array after fetching data

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

#livedata #kotlin #android #mvvm

why is this happened?
I have to navigate first to get the items listed

HomeFragment.kt: https://pastebin.com/97CikvMu

HomeFragmentViewModel.kt: https://pastebin.com/KAhz3d6n

Adapter: https://pastebin.com/Cn99MEZu

```kotlin
 homeFragmentViewModel.todoList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                todoListAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Just update your viewmodel https://pastebin.com/siKLRsGM

Comment: thank you so much.. this now works. so how does it work under the hood? would you like to document it line by line?

Comment: In your HomeFragmentViewModel, the LiveData is an observable data holder class. In your case, it is holding the todo list. So when you get the new todos you need to update the value of live data. 
Original is only change the size of holding data that is not observed.

Comment: what I confuse about is why should we use postValue instead of setValue inside the viewModelScope while the default running thread of it is the main thread?

Comment: postValue is used when you want to set the value from the background
setValue is used when you want to set value from the foreground.